# Undesirable Two Different Logon Photos for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, login, icons, user-accounts

When I reboot my Windows 7 computer, a differently sized, undesirable user icon is displayed instead of the one I want. When I lock my computer, the correct icon is displayed.  I have a customized logon screen, and have cropped part of it and set it to my user icon to give the effect of a clear icon.

This icon is sized differently after ever reboot, and destroys the effect of a clear icon.
How can I change this?

EDIT: It looks like the photo is always stretched for both the logon screen and after I hit the "Switch User" button after I lock the computer. The icon is only properly fit after I login and then lock the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this : [You Can Customize Windows 7 Logon Background Officially](http://www.blogsdna.com/2698/you-can-customize-windows-7-logon-background-officially.htm).

I would guess that the two screens are not displayed with the same resolution, and that you don't have the corresponding images in the directory `%windir%\system32\oobe`. You should have an image with a name such as background1600×1200.jpg (meaning resolution of 1600×1200) for every resolution that Win7 might use.

Comment: I tried above suggested methods. It looks like my actual User Icon is stretched after booting. The resolution of the background remains unchanged between the boot and the lock screens

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?